# Nested queries for Angular4 and Parse Server

Tags: angular, parse-platform, ionic3

my concept is create a nested query in order to get a list of users that are not friends.

The basic query for Parse Server and Angular 4 is

```
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```

That retrieves the data of table User

Then i have these queries for Friends table

```
query1 = new Parse.Query('Friends');
friendQuery = new Parse.Query.or(this.query1.equalTo('fromUser',Parse.User.current()),this.query1.equalTo('toUser',Parse.User.current()));
```

I am struggling how to combine them to finally get the user list I want.

Thank you very much

Comment: Are you having a direct connection to your mongodb from your phone?

Comment: @misha130 am developing an app with Ionic 3 Framework